# GroovyScriptEngine: load groovy scripts from subfolder

Tags: java, groovy

I have a directory structure like this:

> - .../GroovyScriptsRoot
>
>   - SubfolderName1/script/ScriptName1.groovy
>   - SubfolderName2/script/ScriptName2.groovy
>   - SubfolderName3/script/ScriptName3.groovy
>   - SubfolderName4/script/ScriptName4.groovy
>   - ...

So I basically want to do something like this:

> GroovyScriptEngine engine = new GroovyScriptEngine(new String[]{".../GroovyScriptsRoot"});

I tried it myself but the scripts do not get loaded. The full path to the scripts is required which is not really nice. Is there a workaround of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm OK, I found out what is going on. Naturally, the problem was with me.

The GroovyScriptEngine correctly loads the scripts by their package name - which actually does not have to correspond to the package which they are into.

I was trying to load the scripts by using just their name. Silly.