# Calling methods between groovy scripts with correct parameters

Tags: java, grails, groovy, soapui

I just started learning about groovy and trying to transpose my java code to groovy scripts. Usually java allows you have a class with only methods that you can call from other classes. I wanted to translate that to groovy. I have in one file - lets call it File1- a method like this:

```
def retrieveData(String name){  
// do something
}
```

and in the second file, File2, I call File1 like this:

```
def file1Class = this.class.classLoader.parseClass(new File("../File1.groovy"))
```

and then try to call the method in File1 like this:

```
def data = file1Class.retrieveData("String")
```

but it keeps giving me this error - MissingMethodException:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static File1.retrieveData() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [String] Possible solutions: retrieveData(java.lang.String)
```

so it does recognize that I am sending in the correct number of parameters and even the correct object, but it isn't running the method as it should?
Is there something I am missing? I tried to remove the object definition from the method - in other words - like this:

```
def retrieveData(name){  
// do something
}
```

but that didn't work either. I am clueless about what the next step would be. Can anyone please help push me in the right direction? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer provided in [this StackOverflow reponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004303/load-script-from-groovy-script#9006034).

Use the `GroovyScriptEngine` [class](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/GroovyScriptEngine.html). What does the `GroovyScriptEngine` do? From the docs:

> Specific script engine able to reload modified scripts as well as
>   dealing properly with dependent scripts.

See the example below.

```
def script = new GroovyScriptEngine( '.' ).with {
  loadScriptByName( '..\File1.groovy' )
} 
this.metaClass.mixin script

retrieveData()
```

Note how we use the `loadScriptByName`method to

> Get the class of the scriptName in question, so that you can
>   instantiate Groovy objects with caching and reloading.

This will allow you to access Groovy objects from files however you please.

Comment: I tried that but it completely ignored the classpath. I put in necessary jar files into the ext folder so that the soapUI can have access to it, and it does using the method I referenced in the question, but when I do it that way, it throws a MultipleCompilationErrorsException: unable to resolve class HSSFCell

Comment: Are you trying to call a directory? If so, [check out this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15565961/groovyscriptengine-load-groovy-scripts-from-subfolder#15566768) which describes loading from a subfolder. Also, if you are calling resources that are defined by a relative path, extra care will need to be taken in switching between groovy classes.

Comment: The File1.groovy and the xml holding the File2.groovy are both in the Documents folder. Yes, I had to edit the loadScript by Name to this:`loadScriptByName( '../../../../Users/myname/Documents/File1.groovy' )` but the jar files should go to the SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext folder. So why won't it see it? while reading File1.groovy?

Comment: What did you change it too?

Comment: I changed the directory it was pointing to, so it points to the correct location of the File1.groovy. I even tried moving the File1.groovy file into the folder containing the jars but still nothing

Comment: Can you place all the files in the same directory for testing purposes? If you are going to be calling the Users home directory try something similar to `File user_home = new File("${System.getProperty('user.home')}$fileName".toString())`

Comment: still having the same issues. I moved the xml file containing the File2.groovy and the File1.groovy file to the folder containing the jar files in the SOAP_HOME/bin/ext folder, and its still giving the same error